# Sendgrid BCC not working correctly

Tags: sendgrid

I am using Sendgrid in my Rails application, when I add emails in TO and BCC, then after sending the email through my application, TO email is working fine and I got the email, but when I logged in with the same BCC email in my account(e.g. Gmail), then there is no TO email details and my BCC email shifted in the TO field, so that my email (that means BCC email) is showing into the TO field.

As per the default process, for the BCC email user, TO email details should be in the TO field and my email (BCC email) should show into the BCC field section. But it is not working like that.

Please let me know, how can I achieve this process, so that based on the default functionality, my BCC email will display into the BCC email field instead of TO field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the sendgrid-rails gem and also using the SendGrid::MailInterceptor in it. So that your sendgrid mail configuration file would in the mail.rb initializer file.

You need to move your sendgrid configuration from mail.rb file to your config/environment file and also change the port number.

So the new configuration would be looks like:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :user_name => 'your_sendgrid_username',
  :password => 'your_sendgrid_password',
  :domain => 'yourdomain.com',
  :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  :port => 587,
  :authentication => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

For Ref: https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Frameworks/rubyonrails.html

Comment: @TusharPal I have same problem in java api any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: I am not sure in java but you can check it by protect your mail conf to bypass to any interceptor because it cause a mail defects

Comment: @TusharPal do i need to move just smtp setting or all config of sendgrid. I tried to move only smtp settings after Rails.application.initialize!  but it didn't work. Then i try to move all configs but still facing same issue but issue still persist i do confirm the issue is due to the interceptor
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/zeeshangulzar/57112e74e75a8c5f986e153568a8d6a0/raw/10bb25a561e4a429b68c376abe46a882d48dded5/Sendgrid%2520issue%2520gist